# Custom button in Partner Community

Tags: javascript, community, custom-button, partner-communities

In `Salesforce Partner Community` I want to use a custom JavaScript button.

It has this code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/xdomain/xdomain.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/30.0/integration.js")}

var url = '/apex/ECH_VFP021_PoDCreateSavedCase?isdtp=nv&id=>{!PointofDelivery__c.Id}';
if (sforce.console.isInConsole() || '{!$Profile.Name}' == 'Chile Emergencies') {
srcUp(url);
} else {
window.open(url,'_blank');
}
```

When I click the button, I always receive this error:

> GET https://*/support/console/30.0/integration.js net::ERR_ABORTED

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not mix up api version of the js libs, 26 and 30 in your case.

Also check different api versions e.g. 32, 33, ... 40

Also I've never seen the xdomain.js. Do you know what is does in detail?